# I'm experiencing very slow OpenGL compute shader compilation (10+ minutes) when using larger work groups, is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, compute-shader

So, I'm encountering a really bizarre (at least to me as a compute shader noob) phenomenon when I compile my compute shader using `glGetShaderiv(m_shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status)`. Inexplicably, my compute shader takes much longer to compile when I increase the size of my work groups! When I have one-dimensional work groups, it compiles in less than a second, but when I increase the size of my work groups to 4x1x6, the compute shader takes 10+ minutes to compile! How strange.

For background, I'm trying to implement a light clustering algorithm (essentially the one shown here: http://www.aortiz.me/2018/12/21/CG.html#tiled-shading--forward), and my compute shader is this monster:

```
// TODO: Figure out optimal tile size, currently using a 16x9x24 subdivision

#define FLT_MAX 3.402823466e+38
#define FLT_MIN 1.175494351e-38
#define DBL_MAX 1.7976931348623158e+308
#define DBL_MIN 2.2250738585072014e-308

layout(local_size_x = 4, local_size_y = 9, local_size_z = 4) in;

// TODO: Change to reflect my light structure
// struct PointLight{
    // vec4 position;
    // vec4 color;
    // uint enabled;
    // float intensity;
    // float range;
// };

// TODO: Pack this more efficiently
struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 direction;
    vec4 ambientColor;
    vec4 diffuseColor;
    vec4 specularColor;
    vec4 attributes;
    vec4 intensity;
    ivec4 typeIndexAndFlags;
    // uint flags;
};

// Array containing offset and number of lights in a cluster
struct LightGrid{
    uint offset;
    uint count;
};

struct VolumeTileAABB{
    vec4 minPoint;
    vec4 maxPoint;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) readonly buffer LightBuffer {
    Light data[];
} lightBuffer;


layout (std430, binding = 1) buffer clusterAABB{
    VolumeTileAABB cluster[ ];
};

layout (std430, binding = 2) buffer screenToView{
    mat4 inverseProjection;
    uvec4 tileSizes;
    uvec2 screenDimensions;
};

// layout (std430, binding = 3) buffer lightSSBO{
    // PointLight pointLight[];
// };

// SSBO of active light indices
layout (std430, binding = 4) buffer lightIndexSSBO{
    uint globalLightIndexList[];
};

layout (std430, binding = 5) buffer lightGridSSBO{
    LightGrid lightGrid[];
};

layout (std430, binding = 6) buffer globalIndexCountSSBO{
    uint globalIndexCount;
};

// Shared variables, shared between all invocations WITHIN A WORK GROUP
// TODO: See if I can use gl_WorkGroupSize for this, gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.y * gl_WorkGroupSize.z
// A grouped-shared array which contains all the lights being evaluated
shared Light sharedLights[4*9*4]; // A grouped-shared array which contains all the lights being evaluated, size is thread-count

uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

bool testSphereAABB(uint light, uint tile);
float sqDistPointAABB(vec3 point, uint tile);
bool testConeAABB(uint light, uint tile);
float getLightRange(uint lightIndex);
bool isEnabled(uint lightIndex);

// Runs in batches of multiple Z slices at once
// In this implementation, 6 batches, since each thread group contains four z slices (24/4=6)
// We begin by each thread representing a cluster
// Then in the light traversal loop they change to representing lights
// Then change again near the end to represent clusters
// NOTE: Tiles actually mean clusters, it's just a legacy name from tiled shading
void main(){
    // Reset every frame
    globalIndexCount = 0; // How many lights are active in t  his scene
    uint threadCount = gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.y * gl_WorkGroupSize.z; // Number of threads in a group, same as local_size_x, local_size_y, local_size_z
    uint lightCount  = lightBuffer.data.length(); // Number of total lights in the scene
    uint numBatches = uint((lightCount + threadCount -1) / threadCount); // Number of groups of lights that will be completed, i.e., number of passes


    uint tileIndex = gl_LocalInvocationIndex + gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.y * gl_WorkGroupSize.z * gl_WorkGroupID.z;
    // uint tileIndex = gl_GlobalInvocationID; // doesn't wortk, is uvec3
    
    // Local thread variables
    uint visibleLightCount = 0;
    uint visibleLightIndices[100]; // local light index list, to be transferred to global list

    // Every light is being checked against every cluster in the view frustum
    // TODO: Perform active cluster determination
    // Each individual thread will be responsible for loading a light and writing it to shared memory so other threads can read it
    for( uint batch = 0; batch < numBatches; ++batch){
        uint lightIndex = batch * threadCount + gl_LocalInvocationIndex;

        //Prevent overflow by clamping to last light which is always null
        lightIndex = min(lightIndex, lightCount);

        //Populating shared light array
        // NOTE: It is VERY important that lightBuffer.data not be referenced after this point,
        // since that is not thread-safe
        sharedLights[gl_LocalInvocationIndex] = lightBuffer.data[lightIndex];
        barrier(); // Synchronize read/writes between invocations within a work group

        //Iterating within the current batch of lights
        for( uint light = 0; light < threadCount; ++light){
            if( isEnabled(light)){
                uint lightType = uint(sharedLights[light].typeIndexAndFlags[0]);
                if(lightType == 0){
                    // Point light
                    if( testSphereAABB(light, tileIndex) ){
                        visibleLightIndices[visibleLightCount] = batch * threadCount + light;
                        visibleLightCount += 1;
                    }
                }
                else if(lightType == 1){
                    // Directional light
                    visibleLightIndices[visibleLightCount] = batch * threadCount + light;
                    visibleLightCount += 1;
                }
                else if(lightType == 2){
                    // Spot light
                    if( testConeAABB(light, tileIndex) ){
                        visibleLightIndices[visibleLightCount] = batch * threadCount + light;
                        visibleLightCount += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // We want all thread groups to have completed the light tests before continuing
    barrier();
    
    // Back to every thread representing a cluster

    // Adding the light indices to the cluster light index list
    uint offset = atomicAdd(globalIndexCount, visibleLightCount);
    for(uint i = 0; i < visibleLightCount; ++i){
        globalLightIndexList[offset + i] = visibleLightIndices[i];
    }

    // Updating the light grid for each cluster
    lightGrid[tileIndex].offset = offset;
    lightGrid[tileIndex].count = visibleLightCount;
}

// Return whether or not the specified light intersects with the specified tile (cluster)
bool testSphereAABB(uint light, uint tile){
    float radius = getLightRange(light);
    vec3 center  = vec3(viewMatrix * sharedLights[light].position);
    float squaredDistance = sqDistPointAABB(center, tile);

    return squaredDistance <= (radius * radius);
}

// TODO: Different test for spot-lights
// Has been done by using several AABBs for spot-light cone, this could be a good approach, or even just use one to start.
bool testConeAABB(uint light, uint tile){
    // Light light = lightBuffer.data[lightIndex];
    // float innerAngleCos = light.attributes[0];
    // float outerAngleCos = light.attributes[1];
    // float innerAngle = acos(innerAngleCos);
    // float outerAngle = acos(outerAngleCos);
    // FIXME: Actually do something clever here
    return true;
}


// Get range of light given the specified light index
float getLightRange(uint lightIndex){
    int lightType = sharedLights[lightIndex].typeIndexAndFlags[0];
    float range;
    if(lightType == 0){
        // Point light
        float brightness = 0.01; // cutoff for end of range
        float c = sharedLights[lightIndex].attributes.x;
        float lin = sharedLights[lightIndex].attributes.y;
        float quad = sharedLights[lightIndex].attributes.z;
        
        range = (-lin + sqrt(lin*lin - 4.0 * c * quad + (4.0/brightness)* quad)) / (2.0 * quad);
    }
    else if(lightType == 1){
        // Directional light
        range = FLT_MAX;
    }
    else{
        // Spot light
        range = FLT_MAX;
    }
    return range;
}

// Whether the light at the specified index is enabled
bool isEnabled(uint lightIndex){
    uint flags = sharedLights[lightIndex].typeIndexAndFlags[2];
    return (flags | 1) != 0;
}

// Get squared distance from a point to the AABB of the specified tile (cluster)
float sqDistPointAABB(vec3 point, uint tile){
    float sqDist = 0.0;
    VolumeTileAABB currentCell = cluster[tile];
    cluster[tile].maxPoint[3] = tile;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        float v = point[i];
        if(v < currentCell.minPoint[i]){
            sqDist += (currentCell.minPoint[i] - v) * (currentCell.minPoint[i] - v);
        }
        if(v > currentCell.maxPoint[i]){
            sqDist += (v - currentCell.maxPoint[i]) * (v - currentCell.maxPoint[i]);
        }
    }

    return sqDist;
}
```

Edit: Whoops, lost the bottom part of this!

What I don't understand is why changing the size of the work groups affects compilation time at all? It sort of defeats the point of the algorithm if my work group sizes are too small for the compute shader to run efficiently, so I'm hoping there's something that I'm missing.

As a last note, I'd like to avoid using `glGetProgramBinary` as a solution. Not only because it merely circumvents the issue instead of solving it, but because pre-compiling shaders will not play nicely with the engine's current architecture.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm figuring that this must be a bug in the compiler, since I've replaced the loop in my `sqDistPointAABB` function with:

```
vec3 minPoint = currentCell.minPoint.xyz;
vec3 maxPoint = currentCell.maxPoint.xyz;
vec3 t1 = vec3(lessThan(point, minPoint));
vec3 t2 = vec3(greaterThan(point, maxPoint));
vec3 sqDist = t1 * (minPoint - point) * (minPoint - point) + t2 * (maxPoint - point) * (maxPoint - point);
return sqDist.x + sqDist.y + sqDist.z;
```

And it compiles just fine now, in less than a second! So strange